# How can I click on Google Maps sidebar menu using Selenium through Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

When I execute the code below, the interpreter displays running Process ended, but I receive no output on my headless browser.

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome("F:\\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://www.google.com/maps")
driver.implicitly_wait(10)

menu = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="omnibox-singlebox"]/div[1]/div[1]')
menu.click()
```

I also experiment with This XPath:

```
menu = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="omnibox-singlebox"]/div[1]/div[1]/button')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You should induce **Explicit waits** to let the web elements rendered properly.
2. Prefer `CSS` over `XPATH`.

**Code :**

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
driver.get("https://www.google.com/maps")
time.sleep(5)
try:
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[guidedhelpid='searchbox_hamburger']"))).click()
    print('Clicked on the hamburger button')
except:
    print('Could not click.')
    pass
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Thanks, it's Work Man :D

Answer (score 0):

The Website is taking time to load. But the options are already available. And there is no difference in the attributes of the `button` tag for menu before and after waiting time.

So waiting for the menu to `clickable` does not have an effect. Applying some sleep time after the `driver.get()` worked fine.

```
driver.get("https://www.google.com/maps/@12.3270885,76.6990167,15z")
time.sleep(10)

# wait = WebDriverWait(driver,30)
# wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//button[@class='searchbox-button']")))
menu = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='searchbox-button']")
menu.click()
time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: You can also refer this - [https://sqa.stackexchange.com/a/48990/50815](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/a/48990/50815)

Comment: Thank you so a lot. It is effective. I allow 10 sec of sleep. Thank you once again.

Answer (score 0):

The menu element has a class `searchbox-hamburger-container` which you can use to easily create a css selector for clicking the menu

Instead of this

```
menu = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="omnibox-singlebox"]/div[1]/div[1]')
menu.click()
```

You can do this

```
menu = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.searchbox-hamburger-container")
menu.click()
```

Comment: Thank you so a lot. It is not effective. but When I allow 10 sec of sleep then it just works.